# How do I invert the extrusion along the normals?

Tags: extrude

I am trying to extrude an edge along the normals to direction A (oposite of direction B) but it is always going in direction B, even though I flipped the normals.[image] This image shows direction B.[image] I basically need the oposite of what is shown in this screenshot. The extruded face is going out but I need it to go in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but you can create a transform orientation for any face, edge, or vertex and use the axes that it is oriented on.
Then you can grab along any axis, inlcuding the opposite direction.

[image]

[image]

[image]